# Can't identify this language

Tags: language-identification

I have gotten several text messages from this unknown sender and have not been able to identify the langauge so I can translate it. It appears to be quoting the Bible but I am not sure. I found one place that thinks it is  Bashkir but that doesn't seem to parse correctly when I tried that. Any ideas anyone?:

AMI SARAMEN FONUFAN.   MATEUS 5:14-16 VS14- AMI SARAMEN FONUFAN. EU TELINIMW A NOM WON EU CHUK ESAP TONGENI MONOLA. VS15-ESAP WOR EMAN ARAMAS A KENI EU LAMP O A ANOMU FAN EU SEPI, NGE EPWE ISETA WON LENIAN , PWE EPWE ASARAMA CHON EWE IMW MEINISIN. VS16-IEI USUN AMI SARAM EPWE TITTIN MWEN EKEWE ARAMAS, PWE REPWE KUNA AMI FOFOR MURINA O MWAREITI SEMEMI LON LANG. Amen!! Pwal lesor allim ami meinisin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to be the Micronesian language Chuukese (called in that language *Fosun Chuuk*).
Most of the information I can find on this language comes from the LDS church, which has sent missionaries and is active in proselytizing the region.

The LDS church has published magazine articles in this language; you can see some shared words between this and the text you received and the overall similarity in word structure:

> Ren ach sia weweiti pwe Jises Kraist i ewe Saramen ewe Fonufan, kich
>   sipwe anapano ach nuku non I me winiti saram ngeni ekkewe ekkoch.

https://www.lds.org/liahona/2014/03/the-divine-mission-of-jesus-christ-light-of-the-world?lang=mlg&clang=chk

Here is what they have to say about the island it comes from, Chuuk:

> Inhabited by 48,654 people in 2010, Chuuk is the most populous
>   state of the Federated States of Micronesia.

http://www.cumorah.com/index.php?target=view_case_studies&story_id=205&cat_id=4

Here is a quote from the Wikipedia article on Chuukese (it is a stub):

> Chuukese /tʃuːˈkiːz/, also rendered Trukese /trʌˈkiːz/, is a Trukic
>   language of the Austronesian language family spoken primarily on the
>   islands of Chuuk in the Caroline Islands in Micronesia.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chuukese_language

Comment: Thank you, this is very interesting information- I have never heard of this specific language before.